# How can I send a fax online?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am currently using a DSL connection and there are no dial up connections that I can use easily to switch my computer to a fax machine.

Is there a good online service that can send a fax (PDF format to fax preferably) for me (to/from any international place, specifically I want to be able to send a fax from Trinidad and Tobago to Canada and vice versa later on)?

I also want a cover page to be added and confirmation, is this possible ?

I tried faxzero.com, really annoying and takes forever.

Comment: I'm curious. What's annoying about faxzero? I have used it many times and it worked fine. I can see that if the receiving fax machine is busy then the sending can be slow. The good thing I found was that both .doc and .pdf files can be attached.

Comment: @grokus it was mainly the sending and the confirmation. I have not been able to send any from their site. Delay notification took two hours and an additional hour after that to say it failed.I tried out efax and I liked it alot better. I ended up getting Pamfax in the end. It also had a desktop edition that allowed for a fax-in number integration with Skype.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been really happy with [efax.com](http://www.efax.com/). It's not free, but fairly cheep. It can handle PDF and other file types and works great. I believe you can also receive faxes as well, but have never needed that.

Comment: Faxzero (http://faxzero.com/) allows you to send up to two faxes per day for free. Both .doc and .pdf files can be attached.

Comment: Beware of their charging structure, they once tried (and gave up after I complained) to charge me 15 times for a fax that only successfully sent on the last attempt.

Also, when you leave you have to speak to the customer retention people first - no option to do it online (at least not when I used it)

Answer (score 5):

I use [Freefax](http://www.freefax.co.il) to send free faxes from Israel. The site is in Hebrew only but you can try using Google translate to get over that hurdle.

Answer (score 3):

(here in germany) i use: https://www.fax-senden.de/

Answer (score 0):

PopFax.com offers very good internet fax service. I'm using it for a long time. The price is great, it is reliable, saves a lot of time and leaves me extremely organized. More information on [FAQ](http://en.popfax.com/Fax%20to%20email%20faq.html) page.